# dynamically create form elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hello I have HTML form and I am trying to create div sections of the form on button click event. I have HTML code with javascript like below but it is not adding form elements after the button click event. I need to create the all the rows and cells along with input text boxes as in Person div element and append or add in the Div- Person when we click on AddPerson button. I have some more Div elements which contains other input elements which I need to add or create after clicking the button associated with that Div tag.. Here is sample code for One Div element with 3 input fields and one button. Help would be highly appreciated.The value of i or j variable must be incremented . It is always taking i =1 is it a problem?

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        form
        {
            width: 600px;
            background-color:#FA7300;
            margin: 0px auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    var i=1;
    var j=1;
    //create Person section

    function CreatePerson(divName)
    {
     var y= document.createElement('div');
     y.innerHTML="<br/><input type='text' name='Key_Firstname_'+i+1><br/><input type='text' name='Key_lastname_'+i+1><br/><input type='text' name='Key_DOB_'+i+1>";

     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(y);
    }




    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" name="mainfrm" action="">



    <fieldset style="border:0px; background-color: #ffffff; margin-left:50px; width:500px">

        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:125px">&nbsp;

                </td>
                <td style="width:375px">&nbsp;

                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Acc NUMBER</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input name="Key_Acc_Number_1" size="35" type="text" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Branch NUMBER</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input name="Key_BNumber_1" size="35" type="text" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr><td align="center" COLSPAN="2"> <b>PERSON</b><td></tr>
            <div id="Person">

            <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
                <td align="left">

                    <input name="Key_FirstName_1" size="35" type="text" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
                <td align="left">

                    <input name="Key_Lastname_1" size="35" type="text" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>DOB</td>
                <td align="left">

                    <input name="Key_DOB_1" size="35" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td><button onClick="CreatePerson('Person')">Add Person</button>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </div>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
                 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I modified javascript function to this it is also creating 2 First name and last name text boxes at the top of the page but as soon as code is existing from java script end those text boxes disappeared.

```
var i=2;
var j=2;
function CreatePerson(divName)
    {
     var Y= document.createElement("div");
     Y.id=divName+i;
    // Y.innerHTML="<tr> 
    var appendText="<tr><td>First Name</td><td align="+"left"+"><input name="+"Key_FirstName_"+i+" size="+"35"+" type="+"text"+" /></td></tr><tr><td>Last Name</td></tr><tr><td align="+"left"+"><input name="+"Key_lastName_"+i+" size="+"35"+" type="+"text"+" /></td></tr>"; 

Y.innerHTML=appendText;
     document.getElementById(divName).after(Y);
     i++;
    }
```

Comment: `y.innerHTML="<br/><input type='text' name='Key_Firstname_'+i+1><br/><input type='text' name='Key_lastname_'+i+1><br/><input type='text' name='Key_DOB_'+i+1>;` is missing the closing `"`

Comment: You need to put your js in the bottom

Comment: No you don't @MohitC - the `CreatePerson` function is _defined_ in the head, before div it's applied to exists, but it is not _called_ until the onClick handler fires; and that can only fire after the whole DOM is loaded and rendered.  If you want to talk best-practices, it is best to put your JS in a completely separate `.js` file and trigger things from the DOMContentLoaded event (or jquery `$(document).ready()`)

Comment: Also, since `<button>` elements [default to `type="submit"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), I suggest setting `type="button"` and/or returning `false` from your JavaScript function.

Comment: The code you pasted is missing a closing quote (`"`) at the end of `y.innerHTML = `

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>

var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

[dynamically add form elements via JavaScript](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/)

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: Yes, you did more than just add the missing close-quote `"` that people mentioned. What _else_ did you change? _Why_ did you make the change? Why didn't it work before? (update your answer, don't explain it to me in comments; I already know the answers to the 3 questions I posed here)

Comment: I need to add the entire div section like TR, TD. I am not sure how to do that. I have used <br/> in my javascript code.

Comment: @user2897967 _"I need to add the entire div section like TR, TD"_ — you didn't say that in your question, and I think that should be a separate question once you get your basic error(s) (from this question) solved. First, just be able to add _something_ simple.

Comment: I mentioned in a question that I need to add div section in a table .

Comment: @user2897967 You may want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46776721/edit) to include your latest code (without the typo) and to clarify what's going wrong.